# Doxygen including comments from another file

Tags: c, comments, documentation, doxygen

I usually include a module overview and usage guidelines in comments somewhere at the top of .c files. I would like this information to appear within the detailed description generated by Doxygen but I would not like to repeat this same information in the .h file.

I could include the .c file in the docs and use DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS or \cond around everything apart from the little bit I'd like to include, but this seems inelegant.

Is there some way to include / link a specific comment section from the .c file within the docs for the .h file?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Looks like you look for possibilities like `\include{doc}` or `\snippet{doc}` but to be able to say something relevant please post a small example (in your question)

Comment: I'm using 1.9.4.
Thank you for that - it's quite useful. But I seem to only be able to add code snippets rather than (Doxygen formatted) comments themselves.

Comment: With the option `doc` in the `\snippet{doc}` it is possible to add doxygen formatted comments.